Как можно решить проблему 915. Кубик - 2 acmp?
https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=915
вот как я пытался решить эту задачу:
N, M = map(int, input().split())
field = [[] for _ in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    field[i] = list(map(int, input().split()))

dp = [[[-float('inf')] * 7 for _ in range(M)] for _ in range(N)]

for k in range(1, 7):
    dp[0][0][k] = k * field[0][0]
adjacent_faces = {
    1: (2, 3, 4, 5),
    2: (1, 3, 4, 6),
    3: (1, 2, 5, 6),
    4: (1, 2, 5, 6),
    5: (1, 3, 4, 6),
    6: (2, 3, 4, 5)
}

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        for k in range(1, 7):

            if i + 1 < N:
                for face in adjacent_faces[k]:
                    dp[i + 1][j][face] = max(dp[i + 1][j][face], dp[i][j][k] + face * field[i + 1][j])

            if j + 1 < M:
                for face in adjacent_faces[k]:
                    dp[i][j + 1][face] = max(dp[i][j + 1][face], dp[i][j][k] + face * field[i][j + 1])
result = max(dp[N - 1][M - 1][k] for k in range(1, 7))
print(result)

Застряло на 34 тесткейсе (Time limie exceeded), помогите с оптимизацией моего кода, или буду рад если покажете другое решение

Вначале я перебрал все стороны кубика чтобы получить максимальное число индексе (0,0)
for k in range(1, 7):
    dp[0][0][k] = k * field[0][0]

После открыл map где я указал соседей каждой стороны кубика:
adjacent_faces = {
    1: (2, 3, 4, 5),
    2: (1, 3, 4, 6),
    3: (1, 2, 5, 6),
    4: (1, 2, 5, 6),
    5: (1, 3, 4, 6),
    6: (2, 3, 4, 5)
}

В этой задаче мне надо максимизировать сумму перекатывая кубик на соседние стороны, то есть сторона_кубика*число(х,у)
Дальше мне нужно добраться от (0,0) до (N-1,M-1), но я могу идти только вниз и направо суммируя полученные значения. Внутри цикла я рассматриваю все грани кубика
for k in range(1,7)

далее я пробую все возможные комбинации с соседями, чтобы максимизировать сумму
for face in adjacent_faces[k]

дальше я суммирую все значения
Извините, что не объяснил все сразу.
Попробовал таким способом но упал на 33 тесткейсе
from collections import deque

N, M = map(int, input().split())
field = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(N)]

adjacent_faces = {
    1: (2, 3, 4, 5),
    2: (1, 3, 4, 6),
    3: (1, 2, 5, 6),
    4: (1, 2, 5, 6),
    5: (1, 3, 4, 6),
    6: (2, 3, 4, 5),
}
dp = [[[-float('inf')] * 7 for _ in range(M)] for _ in range(N)]

queue = deque()

for k in range(1, 7):
    dp[0][0][k] = k * field[0][0]
    queue.append((0, 0, k))

while queue:
    x, y, k = queue.popleft()
    for dx, dy in ((1, 0), (0, 1)):
        nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
        if 0 <= nx < N and 0 <= ny < M:
            for face in adjacent_faces[k]:
                new_value = dp[x][y][k] + face * field[nx][ny]
                if new_value > dp[nx][ny][face]:
                    dp[nx][ny][face] = new_value
                    queue.append((nx, ny, face))
print(max(dp[N - 1][M - 1]))



Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Поясните алгоритм вашего решения в вопросе.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, если даже вам непонятно, то я спокоен. А то я думал это только я не понимаю, что тут происходит )

Да вроде всё понятно. Тут фишка условия в том, что не стандартное перекатывание, за ориентацией следить не надо, только на одну из четырёх боковых можно ставить. Мне кажется, что вряд ли получится радикально ускорить, но раза в 3 можно  - запоминать, если на клетке (a,b) один раз посчитали для грани k, то в следующие приходы на эту клетку не считать заново.

O-большое выглядит нормально. Можно улучшить константу: поменять порядок заполнения таблицы, убрать лишние условия.

Вы уверены что превышено время а не память?

То что вы по времени по успеваете - мелочь. Не мелочь - ограничение 16MB памяти. Это означает что вы не должны хранить целиком в памяти ни поле, ни массив dp.

Первый и последний раз эту задачу сдали на Питоне в 2019 году. Сложно.
Ограничение по памяти требуют чтобы поле обрабатывалось по строкам. Ограничения по времени требуют оптимизировать расчёт максимумов (две противолежащие стороны используют общий максимум по "поясу" из клеток их разделяющих.
def main():
    belts = (1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 3, 5), (0, 1, 4, 5)
    cube = 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0

    n, m = map(int, input().split())

    def maxes(g):
        s = tuple(g)
        return [max(s[f] for f in faces) for faces in belts]

    mx = [[0] * 3] * m

    row = list(map(int, input().split()))

    mx[0] = maxes((p + 1) * row[0] for p in range(len(cube)))

    for j in range(1, m):
        mx[j] = maxes(
            (p + 1) * row[j] + mx[j - 1][b] for p, b in enumerate(cube)
        )

    for _ in range(1, n):
        row = list(map(int, input().split()))

        mx[0] = maxes(
            (p + 1) * row[0] + mx[0][b] for p, b in enumerate(cube)
        )

        for j in range(1, m):
            mx[j] = maxes(
                (p + 1) * row[j] + max(mx[j][b], mx[j - 1][b])
                for p, b in enumerate(cube)
            )

    print(max(mx[m - 1]))


main()

Если продолжать рефакторить код можно получить трёхкратный запас по скорости:
def main():
    n, m = map(int, input().split())

    mx0 = [0] + [float('-inf')] * m
    mx1 = mx0[:]
    mx2 = mx1[:]

    for _ in range(n):
        for j, a in enumerate(map(int, input().split())):
            s0 = (1, 6)[a > 0] * a + max(mx0[j - 1], mx0[j])
            s1 = (2, 5)[a > 0] * a + max(mx1[j - 1], mx1[j])
            s2 = (3, 4)[a > 0] * a + max(mx2[j - 1], mx2[j])
            mx0[j] = max(s1, s2)
            mx1[j] = max(s2, s0)
            mx2[j] = max(s0, s1)

    print(max(mx0[m - 1], mx1[m - 1], mx2[m - 1]))


main()


Внутри цикла можно ещё ужать-обфусцировать: s=[(i+1,6-i)[row[j]>0]*row[j] + max(mx[j - 1][i], mx[j][i]) for i in range(3)]   mx[j]=[max(s[i-1],s[i-2]) for i in range(3)]  :)

@MBo, спасибо. Но я для скорости разбил mx на три массива. Глядя на этот код понимаешь зачем в C++ шаблоны а в Lisp макросы. Такие простынки хочется доверить писать компилятору.

Интересно, насколько удалось ускорить для больших размеров по сравнению.с исходным кодом?

@MBo, статистика с ACMP: первый вариант 0,921с, оптимизированный вариант 0,281с. Надо учитывать что ограничение в задаче - одна секунда. Поэтому я так давил на константу.

Понятно, спасибо. Чуть модифицированный код автора заваливался с 1.28 с на 34 тесте - но там могли быть и бОльшие тесты.
